# Move orders shipped under open orders Wpdatatables

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, datatable

I have a table in wpdatatables SQL Query, where to a "Shipped" column I add the shipment date of the goods.
When a job has been sent, by conditional formatting, a line is added to the line that is used to hide it.
I have set default rows per page to 200, but this way I always have to work on the last page, so we should move the orders shipped under open orders, so I can always work on the first page.
Is it possible with an SQL Query code?

The rows in red are orders shipped, while the others are open orders, I would like to bring all the orders shipped far from the orders in progress, but always maintaining an ascending order by date on the column "dataconsegnapapistista"
[image]

This is the code I use now:

```
SELECT wp_wpdatatable_5.`wdt_ID`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`numeroprotocollo`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`datainserimento`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`cliente`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`codice`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`tipoattrezzatura`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`ordinatoda`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`note`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`elettrodiottone`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`guide`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`punzoni`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`sotto`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`sopra`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`contorniluxottica`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`fustelle`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`pinze`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`spingianime`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`dataconsegnaprevista`,
       wp_wpdatatable_5.`speditoil`
FROM wp_wpdatatable_5
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It sounds like an `order by` or `where` clause would solve your problem.

Comment: I added an image with description. Thank you for your suggestion.